# Dash has stopped responding

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, unity-dash

I am running Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit and just recently Dash has stopped responding. It still exists as an icon in the launcher but it will not open. The super key will not open dash either.Does anyone have any suggestions to fix this problem. I have recently tried re-installing untiy but that hasnt seemed to help but as im new to linux I may have incorrectly followed through in terminal.

cheers,
    new linux convert

Answer (score 1):

This finally worked:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

command `unity --reset` from the terminal